# Why can't I run phpinfo() in my docker container?

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

I am trying to get a connection between my php-fpm docker container and an RDS Postregsql. I found that I was getting an error in my php application "call to undefined function pg_connect()". So I thought that maybe the issue was that I didn't have pgsql driver enabled in my php.ini. So I tried to enable it, by first adding a line to my Dockerfile, rebuilding the image, then I brought down the container and brought it up again. But I am getting the same error "call to undefined function pg_connect(). So I'd like to run phpinfo() in the container to see if the pgsql driver is loaded. I tried to run it by using docker exec 4822 /bin/bash to open a cli to the container, but the host cli just comes back with a $. How can I run phpinfo() in the container so I can figure out why $DB2 = $this->load->database('postgres', TRUE) is failing with the above error? I am using Codeigniter and here is the connection array:

```
enter code here

enter code here
```

Sorry I can't get the format going. Anyway, here is the dsn
'dsn' => 'jdbc:postgresql://imagesdatabase.cwymdn16cxes.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the $ prompt:

```
php
```

should start the PHP process. Then:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

will display phpinfo() output. You will need to end the php process with a Control-D and then all output should be displayed.

Comment: I am still having an issue. What I don't understand is why we think that typing  php -a will run interactive php within the container, rather than on the host?

Comment: for those still wondering: running `docker exec -it php sh` where `php` is your php container, you can then do `php <?php phpinfo(); `  once you get a prompt. alternatively, if using docker desktop, click the `>_` CLI button for the container and you;ll have a prompt inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

This will help you, how to use `interactive command line PHP`.

If `DockerImage` is based on `PHP` or has `PHP installed` in `docker container` then you can use this feature. What you need to do in `docker terminal` is run following command

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo 5+8;
13
```

Comment: I was trying to run this in the php_fpm container. Turns out that I needed to run it in the Apache Container. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Well I finally realized that since my under development is php why not just insert phpinfo() into the start up. I did that and it works great! All that effort just to confirm that the pgsql driver is not loaded! At this rate it will take me the rest of my life to finish my application .